# .net Core Web API with Angular not able to access after deploying in IIS from publish folder

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

In my .net core 3.1 application, I have Web API and angular app added to clientFolder.

And the issue is when I directly run the application from Visual Studio using IISServer, everything runs perfectly.

however after deploying the application in IIS from a publish folder, the web API Part is not working.

The UI as well as the Swagger part loaded.

StartUp File:

```
namespace TestApp
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        readonly string MyAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(MyAllowSpecificOrigins,
                                  builder =>
                                  {
                                      builder.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod();
                                  });
            });
            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            // In production, the Angular files will be served from this directory
            services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/TestAppUI";
            });
            services.AddSwaggerGen();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            }
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "DO Admin API");
            });

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            if (!env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseCors(MyAllowSpecificOrigins);

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            });

            app.UseSpa(spa =>
            {
                spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

                if (env.IsDevelopment())
                {
                    spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The API calls return 304 not modified with some HTML Response

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>TestAppUI</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.dc819048a0054fcb6932.css"></head>

<body class="main-body">
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.cdfb0ddb511f65fdc0a0.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.f19fc0a3e24e5df6cb6e.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.dc4fd68f0a557169bd87.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es2015.d0017b3969d32d14fb8c.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.d0017b3969d32d14fb8c.js" nomodule defer></script></body>

</html>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong while deploying.

UPDATE

I also have following web.config content

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\DOAdminV2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Without the above I get this error

[image]

Comment: Can you also share how your api method return the result?

Comment: Do you have any url rewrite rules in your IIS web.config? If you have try removing them, the rewriting to the angular app is already handled by the middleware.

Comment: @J.Loscos I do have a web.Config with Content as updated in description. If I dont have that I get the error as in the Question Description

Comment: @tontonsevilla the Method Returns ActionResult<IEnumerable<Model1>> EX: [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult<IEnumerable<Config>> GetConfigs()
        {
            return ConfigRepository.GetAllConfigs();
        }

Comment: @TBA, what is this for? `<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\DOAdminV2.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />`

Comment: Looks like it added for the In Process deployment